# What is the correct way of understanding SLD rules and filters?

Tags: geotools

I am working on a JavaFX renderer for shape map files, and I am trying to nail down a few details of how SLD styling is applied to features.

I have an SLD feature type style for a feature type T as follows (abstracting from all the XML):

```
Rule 1
    Filter 1
    Symbolizer 1
Rule 2
    Filter 2
    Symbolizer 2
Else Rule
    Symbolizer 3
```

There are two ways that this style can be understood in terms of how features are rendered and styled.

**Way 1**:

```
for each feature f that is of type T
    for each rule R_i
        if f satisfies Filter_i
            apply Symbolizer_i to f
            break the **inner** loop on rules

    //  get here if no rule applied
    apply PointSymbolizer_3 to f
```

**Way 2**:

```
for each rule R_i
    L = the set of features of type T that satisfy Filter_i
    for each feature f in L
        apply Symbolizer_i to f

for each feature f that was not in any L
    apply Symbolizer_3 to f
```

Which of these is the correct interpretation? (or maybe neither are).

Is there a specification/definition somewhere that defines what the correct interpretation/semantics of such styles is?

thx
g

Comment: Way 1 is correct because the styling rules are applied in the order they are defined in the SLD file. The first rule that matches a feature is applied, and then the loop is broken, moving on to the next feature. If no rule matches a feature, the else rule is applied. While Way 2, is not correct because it would apply all the symbolizers to a feature at once, which contradicts the principle of applying only one symbolizer per feature.

Comment: "not correct because it would apply all the symbolizers to a feature at once" -- I am not sure I understand this statement. Symbolizer_i is only applied to feature f if feature f matches Filter_i. Under "normal" circumstances (where the filters are disjoint), this means each feature would only have one symbolizer applied to it.

Comment: That statement is bit misunderstanding. Not that all symbolizers are applied to a feature at once, but rather that the rules are evaluated in a certain order, and the first rule that a feature satisfies is applied. In Way 2, if a feature satisfies Filter_i, then Symbolizer_i is applied to that feature, and the process moves on to the next feature. If a feature does not satisfy any of the filters, then the Else rule is applied, and Symbolizer_3 is applied to that feature.

Comment: I agree that Way 1 probably makes more sense. But do you know if there is any formal spec that actually **defines** the order in which things are supposed to be done.

Comment: It's defined by the OGC SLD spec

Comment: For the spec, is that [this document](https://portal.ogc.org/files/?artifact_id=16700)